# Variable undefined in Java script

Tags: javascript

```
function getForm()  
{   
  var arry =[ [0,1] ,[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]];         
  var a;     
  var x = 1 ;        
  console.log(x);     
  for (i = 0; i < arry.length; ++i)      
  {         
    if (arry[i][0] == x)          
    {             
      a = arry[i][1];          
    }         
    console.log(a);  
  } 
}
```

I  am totally new to JavaScript, I was running this programming in Firebug. I have got the output as undefined I was expecting the output x=1,a=2(I mean first console.log and second one). I was defined all the variables inside the function only.

Comment: What line do you get the error on?

Comment: You just define a function and never called it. So, firebug after declaring functions, says `undefined`

Comment: I have got error in the 3rd line , It was taking array  in the for loop as an normal text not in blue color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is `console` print outside the `if` condition, so first time condition going `false` (return `undefined`) and second time condition satisfied (then print correctly),

you should move `console` into `if` condition,

```
<script>
    var arry =[ [0,1] ,[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]];         
    var a;     
    var x = 1 ;        
    console.log(x);     
    for (i = 0; i < arry.length; ++i){         
         if (arry[i][0] == x){        
            a = arry[i][1];          
            console.log(a);  
         }         
    } 
</script>
```

Console Result:

```
 1
 2
```

View on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0ngxj2fk/)

Comment: Yeah, It was working fine !! If I declare array outside the function , I am not able to access it !!

Comment: But why did not the x print initially? I mean this    var x = 1 ;

Comment: @Clouds off-cause we print x initially but OP have some purpose to not print initially.

Answer (score 0):

You are logging `a` in each iteration, but `a` is not set until the `if` statement is `true`, which only happens in the second iteration.

Lets go through it step by step:

```
// 1. iteration
i = 0
arry[i][0] == x => false // 0 == 1
console.log(a) // undefined

// 2. iteration
i = 1
arry[i][0] == x => true // 1 == 1
a = arry[i][1] // a = 2
console.log(a) // 2

// 3. iteration and beyond
// the condition is always false, so `a` keeps its value
i = 2
arry[i][0] == x => false // 2 == 1
console.log(a) // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

It outputs `undefined` because the first time you call `console.log(a)` the variable `a` is undefined.

You declare `a` without a value:

```
var a;
```

Then in the first iteration of the loop you check for this:

```
if (arry[i][0] == x)
```

When `i` is `0`, `arry[i][0]` is also `0`.  And you defined `x` as `1`.  0 does not equal 1, so this condition is false.  Which means the code inside the conditional block, which sets a value to `a`, doesn't execute.  But then the code after it does.

At that time `a` is undefined, so `console.log(a)` logs `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

console.log(x) is working fine

in first interation  , the if condition is false , so 'a' will not get initialized and hence in console you will get undefined , next iteration onwards you will get the desired console output,

if you are running on firebug extra 'undefined' will be displaed because calling a function which does not return anything will result 'undefined' on the console

Answer (score 0):

You declared the function but never invoked. Invoking the function will give you the desired results, since when I tried to execute the statements without function wrap, i.e

```
    var arry =[ [0,1] ,[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]];
    var a;     
    var x = 1 ;        
    console.log('Value of x', x);     
    for (i = 0; i < arry.length; ++i) {         
       if (arry[i][0] == x) {             
          a = arry[i][1];          
       }         
       console.log('Value of a in ', i , 'iteration' ,a);  
    } ;
```

this was the output:

Value of x 1

Value of a in 0 iteration 2864415817892.274

Value of a in 1 iteration 2

Value of a in 2 iteration 2

Value of a in 3 iteration 2